# Switch language at runtime on a multilanguage site using python-i18n

Tags: python, internationalization, runtime, multilingual

I have created a multi-language DASH app via python-i18n and yml files as described by Arjan in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_KlPZ5qBOU

The intention is to translate the text (headers, labels, etc) in the app and allow the user to change the language via a dropdown. Everything works fine when manually changing the LOCALE setting before running the app.

According to the attached video (at about 4:27) it should be possible to use a callback to update the language. I have the dropdown and callbacks set up and use

```
dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True)
```

to trigger the change but after the refresh the original langauge persists.

The problem seems to be that

```
    i18n.set("locale", loc_code)
    i18n.load_path.append(locale_path)
```

are executed early in the initial loading and regardless if those are changed at runtime the reload/refresh does not seem to activate after the refresh performed by dcc.Location.

Any ideas on how this should be done?

I have tried several ways to set this via callbacks:

```
    i18n.set("locale", loc_code)
    i18n.load_path.append(locale_path)
```

but is seems that the original language setting persists.

It is mentioned that these i18n lines should be called before the defining the app.layout. Not sure what part of the app that the reload affects and how to make that incorporate the language change.

% Update
The following code works as intended, but my large app has another structure with subfolders and separate files for callbacks/layout/etc. Thus it appears that the problem is linked to the structure.

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import dcc, html

import i18n
from pathlib import Path


def setlang(loc):
    global LOCALE
    LOCALE = loc
    i18n.set("locale", LOCALE)
    i18n.load_path.append(locale_path)

# initial language code
LOCALE = "se"
# path to yml files with translations
parent_directory = Path(__file__).parent
locale_path = parent_directory / "locale"

setlang(LOCALE)

INITIAL = '1+1=2'

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


def serve_layout():
    return html.Div([
        dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=True),
        i18n.t("general.designation"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(id='important-info', value=INITIAL, persistence=True),
        html.Button("Forget it!", id='clear-info'),
        dcc.Dropdown(
                id='ldropdown',
                options=['se', 'en'],
                placeholder='placeholder_text')
    ])


app.layout = serve_layout


@app.callback(
   Output("url", "href"),
   Input(component_id='ldropdown', component_property='value'),
   prevent_initial_call=True
)
def create_dow(lang_code_dd):
    setlang(lang_code_dd)
    return "/"


@app.callback(
    Output('important-info', 'value'),
    Input('clear-info', 'n_clicks')
)
def clear_persistence(n):
    return INITIAL if n else dash.no_update


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I had to do the same in javascript, and I had to reload all text which needed to be translated. Perhaps you need to do the same. There the command was: `i18n.changeLanguage('en');`

Comment: I would look at/search online about the python-i18n documentation and how to change language, for example here: https://lokalise.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-python-i18n/. A quote: "A challenge that you may have faced earlier in this tutorial is to automatically create a master list of strings to translate. You will need to use a tool such as Babel to help you automatically collect all strings in your application that need to be translated."

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Matthias. It appears to be the complex structure that I have in the app that is causing the language switching to fail. Or maybe there is another command to force the update. Anyway, the condensed example above works (if yml files containing the translations are placed in /locale).